# Use Fips compliant hashing algorithm for validate token in System.IdentityModel

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, jwt, adal

I am using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll (version 5.1.4) to validate token and it us using SHA256Managed for hashing. Is it possible to force this to use Fips complaint ones like SHA256CryptoServiceProvider. Here is the exception when FIPS is enabled

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.ObjToHashAlgorithm(Object hash